# Hotels with outdoor swimming pools for winter

Tags: hotels, switzerland, swimming

I am interested in visiting Switzerland in winter, but I am also looking for staying at a place where I can enjoy outdoor swimming. 'The Cambrian' in Adelboden is the only hotel I could find through online research which can boast an outdoor heated swimming pool which can be used in winter and it has a great view as well.

Are there any other 5/4 star hotels in Switzerland where you can enjoy a heated outdoor swimming pool in winter?

Comment: While I don't know any particular hotels which fit your criteria, I would have a look at thermal baths. Here's a [list](http://www.valais.ch/en/activities/wellness-water/thermal-baths) of those in the region of Valais. I personally know the stations of Leukerbad, Ovronnaz and Saillon and at least the two former have public baths with very nice outdoor areas with great views (if you are into mountain panoramas). I'm not sure if the hotels there have their own thermal pools, but it might be worth looking into something in those towns.

Comment: You do realise the typical winter temperatures (and snowfall) in Switzerland, and the extreme cost this would involve, right?

Comment: Yes but I am pretty sure there would be people willing to pay for the luxury

Comment: @CMaster Actually it seems to be a thing right now, I now several that opened recently in the Alps. But usually in thermal baths or public spa/swimming pool complexes in ski resorts, not specifically inside an hotel. It could be because of the cost issue you mentioned, though, as you can charge for the entrance and reach more people than a single hotel could.

Comment: There's also [Hotel Villa Honegg](http://villa-honegg.ch/#!/en/spa/indoor-and-outdoor-pools/) and quite a few others. Doing a [Google *Image* search for `switzerland hotel winter heated pool`](https://www.google.ch/search?q=switzerland+hotel+winter+heated+pool&source=lnms&tbm=isch) and then picking out interesting candidates from there seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a list, or several unique answers.  If a person posts one correct pool, is the OP going to accept it? Doesn't seem so in current format.

Comment: @MarkMayo I don't think there would be many answers to this questions to make a list. I was like expecting only one or two more hotels in the country... Or actually even none... Hotels with heated swimming pools in winter are very rare...

Comment: The problem with the open ended list form though, is that multiple answers can be equally correct. A could reply with Hotel XYZ, and B could reply with Hotel JJT.  Which would be more correct? SE tends to try and discourage that format, generally.

Comment: But we'll see how we go. I'll have a look now and litmus test this, I'm sure I could find another hotel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Gstaad Palace Hotel](http://www.palace.ch/palace-spa/swimming-pools/)  fits your needs.  It has both indoor and outdoor pools, and it states that the outdoor pool is available in winter ("including winter outdoor pool").

The hotel is a 5-star luxury hotel, and is situated in Gstaad, a village in the canton of Bern, in Switzerland.

Comment: This one and the Villa Honegg mentioned in the comments are the only ones that fit the criteria it seems. Will accept the answer if no other answers come in a while.